# layoutTemplate not working correctly with 0.8

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I thought that having something like:

```js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate : "template"
});
```

and then

```html
<template name="template">
<head>
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    {{> menu}}
    {{> yield}}
</body>
</template>
```

would continue to work after the last update. Any idea what changes need to be made in order to keep my layout working ? Doesn't seem to be described very well anywhere for now.

What I get after rendering the page is just

```
template
```

in the upper left corner of the browser.

Edit1: For some reason, my browser console wasn't printing out any errors before, but it is now. It seems like it's related to accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 - it's trying to use Spark, I'll try changing to the blaze(dev?)  branch and try again.

Edit2: Replaced the appropriate line in the `smart.json` file with this

```json
"accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {
    "git": "https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.git",
    "branch": "blaze"
}
```

It seems to have helped with the errors I am getting in the console, but I still just see the "template" text in the upper left. The "blaze" branch seems to be undergoing active updates, so it's probably just that... will update when I figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

In Meteor 0.8.0 `{{yield}}` is now `{{>yield}}`

Comment: My bad, I did have it changed to {{> yield}}, let me make an edit.